# Cannot get user session from Amazon Cognito User Pools

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am using Amazon's Cognito User Pools to initiate a SAML SSO authentication. I am using `aws-amplify` that is a JavaScript library for application development using cloud services and ReactJS for the front end. There seems to be some issue with trying to use the `currentSession()` function. It doesn't seem that my session is saving the session when using the `Auth.siginIn()` function of the Auth Module of the package. I've tested and successfully signed in with my current test users that I have set in the User Pool. The reason why I want to use the `Auth.currentSession()` function is to verify the session for each view in my application. Below you can see that after the user verifies the login with I send them to my dashboard view to then try and verify the session after the component mounts but it returns an error with no user found. Below is my code I use. I looked at the documentation aws-amplify has on their website but I can't seem to pinpoint the problem.

> Note: Redux is being used to store the response from setUserData and setAuthToken (session
>   response after signing in)

**Login.js**

```
  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    Auth.signIn(this.state.sso, this.state.password)
    .then((res) => {
      this.props.authUser(true)
      this.props.setUserData(res.username)
      this.props.setAuthToken(res.Session)
    })
    .then(() => {
      this.props.history.push("/Dashboard")
    })
    //catches err
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
      alert(e.message)
      this.props.authUser(false)
    })
  }
```

Once user is logged in then user should be pushed to dashboard. Once `componentDidMount()` is called in component lifecycle then I want to check current session to see if still in session.

**Dashboard.js**

```
componentDidMount(){
    debugger;
    console.log(Auth);
    Auth.currentSession().then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    }).catch((e) => {
      alert(e)
    })


    this.props.toggleError(false);
    this.props.toggleNotify()
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authentication flow for SAML is different than users created in the UserPool. `Auth.signIn()` is only used to authenticate users that have been created in the user pool. ([AWS Amplify Documentation](https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/media/authentication_guide.html))

To initiate a SAML authentication flow, follow these steps:

1. Set up your SAML provider as a federated identity in your UserPool
2. Direct users to the SAML SSO page hosted by your AWS UserPool.
3. Users will authenticate through SAML SSO provider and your **UserPool** will send a JWT to your application
4. Use AWS-Amplify `Auth.federatedSignIn()` method to receive AWS IAM credentials(that will be managed by AWS-Amlify

This guide is a great resource for steps 1-3: [Amazon Cognito User Pools supports federation with SAML](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/amazon-cognito-user-pools-supports-federation-with-saml/).

For step 4:

```
Auth.federatedSignIn(
    // Initiate federated sign-in with your User Pool  
    'cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/us-west-2_XXXXXXXXX',
    { 
        // the JWT token parsed from the response url
        token: #id_token
    },
    // (optional) a user object (a simple dictionary created from the #access_token)
    user
).then(() => {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Will try this and give feedback on results. Thank you for the detailed answer!

Comment: This ended up working. Thank you very much! I have one more question though. How can I check my current user session to see if it's expired. Should I do a Auth.signIn too after the federatedSignIn? I want to be able to check the session for each view loaded to verify if the session is still valid

Comment: EDIT: I figured out my issue. You must set up the oauth configuration parameter for hosted UI in AWS Cognito; Hopefully this helps other people with this issue!